# Weird chemfig 1.33 behaviour with polymerdelim

Tags: include, chemfig

I observed a very weird behaviour regarding `chemfig` and the polymer delimiters. I have created a minimal working example:

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman]{article}
\include{preamble}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{\vphantom{CH_2}-[@{op,.75}]CH_2-CH_2-[@{cl,0.25}]}
    \polymerdelim[height = 5pt, indice = \!\!n]{op}{cl}
\end{document}
```

`preamble.tex`:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
```

I get the following output from this:

[image]

As you can see, the brackets are next to the formula whereas they should be around the formula. When I comment the include statement in `main.tex` and instead uncomment the two lines below, everything works like it should.

How is this possible? I want to have the preamble in a separate document though, because it is much longer in my real document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use `\input` for the preamble.

Comment: @TeXnician why would the make a difference? Isn't `\include` more or less just `\input` in the preamble anyways?

Comment: @daleif I have no clue, but usually sticking to `\input` does reduce strange interactions, that's why I suggested it.